# Service principal expiry query command not working

Tags: azure, azure-cli

Looking for an automated way to identify a list of service principals Expiry date in advance and notify the related team if the expiry date is within 60 days of span. I tried below bash command in azuredevops pipeline, but its not providing any output.

```
az ad sp credential list --id "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx" --query "[].endDate" -o tsv
```

Comment: What attempts did you make to troubleshoot the problem?

Answer (score 1):

> I tried below bash command in azuredevops pipeline, but its not providing any output.

```
az ad sp credential list --id "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx" --query "[].endDate" -o tsv
```

Because of [the discontinuation of Azure Active Directory (Azure AD) Graph](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/migrate-azure-ad-graph-overview), `Azure CLI Version 2.37.0` will incorporate the `Microsoft Graph API` to replace the underlying `Active Directory Graph API`

The `az ad app credential list`  command is updated instead of `az ad sp credential list`, refer this [Ms Doc](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/issues/94096)  by `schaffererin` for more details.

To display the **Azure Service principal expiry date**, you can use the following command.

**Old command:**

```
az ad sp credential list --id 48bb608e-4779-465a-xvxvxvxvxvxvxvxvxve7d62fbc23 --query "[].endDate" -o tsv
```

**Updated command:**

```
az ad app credential list --id 48bb608e-hfhfhfh-465a-fhfhfh-2fe7d62fbc23 --query '[].endDateTime' --output tsv
```

**Output:**

[image]